# Incompatible Windows docker image in AWS ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs

I have created a standard Windows cluster in AWS Elastic Container Services (ECS) and am trying to deploy an ASP.Net docker image (microsoft/aspnet:4.7.1-windowsservercore-1709) to it and get the following error

> Status reason CannotPullContainerError: a Windows version
>   10.0.16299-based image is incompatible with a 10.0.14393 host

My application is a ASP.Net WebAPI application using .Net Framework 4.6.1.

My docker file is

```html
FROM microsoft/aspnet:4.7.1-windowsservercore-1709
ARG source
WORKDIR /inetpub/wwwroot
COPY ${source:-obj/Docker/publish} .
```

Can anyone suggest what image I could deploy?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Change your FROM to `aspnet:4.7.1-windowsservercore-ltsc2016` and it should resolve your issue. Keep in mind the image size for this tag is considerably larger than 1709.

Answer (score 1):

We also got the following message when using AWS ECS:

> CannotPullContainerError: a Windows version 10.0.16299-based image is incompatible with a 10.0.14393 host

After a lot of trial and error we found that we were using .NetCore **SDK 2.2** and AWS ECS wants **2.1**. The developer made changes in Visual Studio 2017 and to the Dockerfile to reference 2.1 instead of 2.2. Once that was done ECS was able to consume it and we had a running state.
Unfortunately the error was not as descriptive and we went down the rabbit hole before discovering what really was our problem.